# how to counter pagination show in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, slider

I used the slider where i got bug occur. I wanted to show counter pagination on slider but i was unable to do this. In form of Current Number of Page/ Total number of pages like 1/4,2/4 and so on.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJRqQj

```
  <div id="credit"><br>Slide No.<span id="count">1/4</span><br></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the left and right buttons click functions. Also do not forget to update the automatic slider accordingly. I'm also sure you can get the total index somewhere within so that you don't have to hardcode the "/4" part. Update the below functions:

```
var leftArrow = $('<div>', {'class': 'jislider__left-arrow'}).click(function () {
                animate.control(--animate.index);
        document.getElementById("count").textContent = animate.index+"/3";
            });
var rightArrow = $('<div>', {'class': 'jislider__right-arrow'}).click(function () {
                animate.control(++animate.index);
        document.getElementById("count").textContent = animate.index+"/3"
            });
```

This will not be enough, you probably should not hardcode the denominator "/4" part as well. I do not know the library you use, but I guess this is sufficient to give you the overall number of "unique" divs with different source:

```
var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".jislider__img"))
.map(function(d,i){return {node:d,url:getComputedStyle(d).backgroundImage}})
.reduce(function(ac,d,i,a){
    !ac.some(function(dd,ii){return dd.url === d.url})
        ? ac.push(d) 
        : void(0);
    return ac
},[]).map(function(d,i){
    return d.node;
})
```

x.length is 3 in your case. So although you have 5 divs, you have 3 images. You can also see it in the dots below (3 dots are there in your carousel). For the left and right arrow functions above, calculate `var l = x.length` before hand, and then you can do:

```
document.getElementById("count").textContent = animate.index+"/" + l;
```

so you don't have to hardcode it. I had to modify your slider a bit, a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/szwr20ec/5/

Comment: Hello @ibowankenobi Thanks for your great answer. will you please check the codepen please i named here Slide No.1/4, i want there will you please codepen update over my code. so then easliy for me. Thanks alot. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJRqQj

Comment: and also please tell me that where i update that code to solve my issue. for that will you please update your code over my codepen code thanks alot

Comment: Hi, I don't normally use codepen, I use jsfiddle, but I made an imgur link here: https://imgur.com/a/otrzj2X   Copy pasted part is highlighted

Comment: Yeah thank you so much. it's worked properly. but will you please tell me why you name numeric static here. 3 is it any method to count images automatically just asking is it possible. Thanks

Comment: Because i have four albums where that used. so that's why i told you is it possible to count first automatically images then start our count. means (1/4) 1 is our count which is working now well and i want 4 count. is it possible, Thanks

Comment: means if i have four pics then automatically count 4 pics

Comment: I think you have 3 unique images there!  And then your slider library creates 5 divs, 2 of which have the same src!

Comment: Hello Thanks for your response i'm glad to talk with you. just check your code and implement in my project i got bug and my bug is that you make nav click function run counter which is ok but when i refresh page it's show nothing in counter when i click on nav then counter function run. is it possible refresh page staring show 1/3 then click nav then show 2/3 and so on... Hope you understand and thank you again for help me. Please tell me how to solve that bug. Thanks

Comment: Hello @ibowankenobi please check my above comment please i got a bug upper please tell me how to solve this. Thanks

Comment: I think I fixed it. Here is the fiddle, I just changed bit of css so revert it back to original. https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/szwr20ec/5/

Comment: OMG it's awesome @ibowankenobi

Comment: Thanks alot for help :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck

Comment: just one question will you please tell me when i get images from subfolder it's didn't get did you know where is that occur.

Comment: means when i get image from image/.jpg it's worked when i get image from image/subimages/.jpg it's didn't get. :(

Comment: yes i know but is this any code to solve that bug thanks

Comment: that's not bug james, you need to find a way to get the correct url.

Comment: because my images are in subfolder so how to get that :(

Comment: yes i know but i didn't find way to get images and also @ibowankenobi images are scroll to left and when i refresh it's show 3/3 it is way show 1/3 and then not reverse thanks again for give my answer :)

Comment: Your slider library goes backwards, that's why it starts from 3/3 and goes to left, that's the normal behavior. In your original example it also always goes left, I do not know how to change it. Maybe you should read about that library a bit.

Comment: ohhhh really you don't know how to do this then how should i know that. :(

Comment: i show you all the code @ibowankenobi that's the all code. from that i didn't have more code. please tell me how to do this